# My computer suddenly stops and shows weird flickering patterns

Tags: windows-10

If I restart the PC, it works fine again .I have no control during flickering .I have Intel HD graphics 3000. Any solutions?

Comment: 1) Did the start of the flickering happen just after something else, like installing a new program, or perhaps a Windows update? 2) Are the flickering patterns like small squares all over the screen? 3) Is this a laptop computer?

Comment: This problem may be related to video memory problems. Overheating, for example...

Comment: Have any images of it? What exactly does "I have no control during flickering" mean, has the computer completely frozen except for the flickering? How do you restart it? Tried turning the mmonitor off & back on (if it's separate), or unplug & reconnect?